# The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ has partial sums $S_{n}=\frac{N}{N+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{100}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions.

Comment: Do you know what a "partial sum" is?  Do you know how that notion relates to the convergence of an infinite series?

Comment: Hint: $S_n = \frac{N}{N+1}=\frac{N+1-1}{N+1}=1-\frac{1}{N+1}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

- What is the **definition** of $S_n$?
- What is the definition of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$? In particular, how is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ connected to $S_n$?